# Sql #table vs Join with in Join, which is better in performance wise

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I have query like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM Tabel1
JOIN Table2 ON ...
JOIN 
    (SELECT * 
     FROM Table3 
     JOIN Table4 ON ....) as X ON Table2.Col1 = X.Col1
```

And my manager instructed me not use this and asked me to move the whole "X part to a `#temp`" table and make a join with `#temp`.

I can't understand what the problem with above code is ...

Comment: For the performance you must include your `DB` structure that u create.

Comment: Your manager said what? @yogesh is right, structure will greatly affect performance and any discussion about it... You would get a far more efficient query if you merged the two statements though, definitely avoid nested queries if you can, and with this partial example i think you can.

Comment: Thanks dude... I rewrote it with #table...